# 3 sequences which are convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $a_0, b_0, c_0\in \mathbb{R}$ and $k>0$. If
>   \begin{align}
> a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}b_n+\frac{k}{k+1}c_n\\
> b_{n+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}c_n+\frac{k}{k+1}a_n\\
> c_{n+1}=\frac{1}{k+1}a_n+\frac{k}{k+1}b_n
> \end{align}
>   Prove that $(a_n), (b_n),(c_n)$ are convergent.

I know that they are all convergent to $\frac{a_0+b_0+c_0}{3}$ and I have a geometrical solution.

However, I'm interested in a purely analytical one. I got that $(a_n+b_n+c_n)$ is constant and then I tried to get a relation only in terms of say $(a_n)$, but this worked only when $k=1$.

Comment: Only an idea: Put $u_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$, and with $j=\exp(2i\pi/3)$, $v_n=a_n+jb_n+j^2c_n$, $w_n=a_n+j^2b_n+jc_n$. Then $u_{n+1}=u_n$, $v_{n+1}=\frac{kj+j^2}{1+k} v_n$, and $w_{n+1}=\frac{j^2k+j}{k+1}w_n$. So you can compute $u_n, v_n,w_n$ easily, and use that $u_n+v_n+w_n=3a_n$, $u_n+j^2v_n+jw_n=3b_n$, $u_n+jv_n+j^2w_n=3c_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to use linear algebra to find the closed form of each sequence.  First write your three equations as a matrix equation
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1} \\ c_{n+1} \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{k+1} & \frac{k}{k+1} \\
\frac{k}{k+1} & 0 & \frac{1}{k+1} \\
\frac{1}{k+1} & \frac{k}{k+1} & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \\ c_n \end{pmatrix}
  $$

Let's call the matrix above $A$.  One might notice that $A$ has nice properties, for instance, it is [doubly stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix).  Computing the [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of $A$ yields
$$ \operatorname{char}(A) = \det(A - xI) = x^3 - \frac{3k}{(k+1)^2}x - \frac{k^2 - k + 1}{(k+1)^2} $$
Notice that one of the roots of this polynomial is $x=1$.  To find the other two roots we can do [polynomial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_division)
$$ \frac{\operatorname{char}(A)}{x-1} = x^2 + x + \frac{k^2 - k + 1}{(k+1)^2} $$
and the quadratic formula with some simplifying gives us the other two roots
$$ x = \frac{-1}{2} \pm \frac{i \sqrt{3}}{2} \left( \frac{k-1}{k+1} \right)$$
These roots are the [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of $A$.  For simplicity let's call the two complex roots $w$ and $\overline{w}$.  Solving for the [eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) of $A$ we have
$$A \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 1 \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
just like you pointed out earlier.

Now for the other two eigenvectors there are two cases.  The easier one is when $k=1$, which means
$$A \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\hspace{.15 in} \text{and} \hspace{.15 in}
A \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = -\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus we can diagonalize $A$ as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
and computing the inverse of the last matrix means
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & (-\frac{1}{2})^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & (-\frac{1}{2})^n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ b_0 \\ c_0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and computing all the matrix multiplication yields
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 - (-\frac{1}{2})^n(-2a_0 + b_0 + c_0)) \\
b_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 - (-\frac{1}{2})^n(a_0 - 2b_0 + c_0)) \\
c_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 - (-\frac{1}{2})^n(a_0 + b_0 - 2c_0))
\end{align*}
It gets a little trickier when $k \not = 1$.  Recall that we called the two complex eigenvalues $w$ and $\overline{w}$.  A little complex algebra will give us
$$A \begin{pmatrix} -\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w - \frac{k}{k-1} \\ \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w + \frac{1}{k-1} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = w \begin{pmatrix} -\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w - \frac{k}{k-1} \\ \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w + \frac{1}{k-1} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$A \begin{pmatrix} -\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)\overline{w} - \frac{k}{k-1} \\ \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)\overline{w} + \frac{1}{k-1} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \overline{w} \begin{pmatrix} -\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)\overline{w} - \frac{k}{k-1} \\ \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)\overline{w} + \frac{1}{k-1} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Our calculations will look a little simpler if we use $z = -\left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w - \frac{k}{k-1}$ and note that $\overline{z} = \left(\frac{k+1}{k-1}\right)w + \frac{1}{k-1}$.  Then we can diagonalize $A$
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & z & \overline{z} \\ 1 & \overline{z} & z \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & w & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \overline{w} \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & z & \overline{z} \\ 1 & \overline{z} & z \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}$$
and computing the inverse of the last matrix means
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_n \\ b_n \\ c_n \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{3} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & z & \overline{z} \\ 1 & \overline{z} & z \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & w^n & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \overline{w}^n \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \overline{z} & z & 1 \\ z & \overline{z} & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} a_0 \\ b_0 \\ c_0 \end{pmatrix}$$
and computing all the matrix multiplication yields
\begin{align*}
a_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 + zw^n(\overline{z}a_0 + zb_0 + c_0) + \overline{z}\overline{w}^n(za_0 + \overline{z}b_0 + c_0))\\
b_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 + \overline{z}w^n(\overline{z}a_0 + zb_0 + c_0) + z\overline{w}^n(za_0 + \overline{z}b_0 + c_0))\\
c_n &= \frac{1}{3}(a_0 + b_0 + c_0 + w^n(\overline{z}a_0 + zb_0 + c_0) + \overline{w}^n(za_0 + \overline{z}b_0 + c_0))
\end{align*}

Since 
$$|w| = \sqrt{\frac{k^2-k+1}{k^2 + 2k + 1}} < 1$$
We have $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} w^n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \overline{w}^n = 0$, thus
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n &= \frac{a_0 + b_0 + c_0}{3}\\
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n &= \frac{a_0 + b_0 + c_0}{3}\\
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} c_n &= \frac{a_0 + b_0 + c_0}{3}\\
\end{align*}

Note: If $k \leq 0$, then
$$|w| = \sqrt{\frac{k^2-k+1}{k^2 + 2k + 1}} \geq 1$$
which is why the sequences diverge for $k \leq 0$.

Comment: Wow, now I see why the general term forms were so hard to get!

Answer (score 2):

This proof is inspired by the geometrical intuition that each iteration of the sequence involves a weighted average of the points of the previous iteration.

Let $M_n = \max(a_n, b_n, c_n)$ and $m_n = \min(a_n, b_n, c_n)$. Let $I_n$ be the point intermediate to these two (if two or more points coincide, simply choose one to be $I_n$).  Let $\alpha = \max(1/(k+1), k/(k+1))$. Then we have

$$ \begin{align} M_{n+1} &\leq I_n + \alpha(M_n - I_n) \leq M_n\\
m_{n+1} &\geq m_n + (1-\alpha)(I_n - m_n) \geq m_n \end{align} $$

Since $M_n$ is a decreasing sequence bounded below (by $m_0$, say), it converges to $M$. Similarly, $m_n$ converges to $m$. $I_n$ is a sequence bounded by $m_0$ and $M_0$ and so by Bolzano-Weierstrass has a convergent subsequence. Let $n_j$ correspond to this subsequence, and $I$ its limit. We know that $n_{j+1} \geq n_j+1$, so we can write the above inequalities as

$$ \begin{align} M_{n_{j+1}} &\leq I_{n_j} + \alpha(M_{n_j} - I_{n_j})\\
m_{n_{j+1}} &\geq m_{n_j} + (1-\alpha)(I_{n_j} - m_{n_j})\end{align} $$

We can now freely take the limit $j \to \infty$ to yield

$$ \begin{align} M &\leq I + \alpha(M-I) \\
m &\geq m + (1-\alpha)(I - m)\end{align}$$

Rearranging these gives $M \leq I$ and $m \geq I$. This is only possible if $M = I = m$. Hence $a_n, b_n, c_n$ converge.